# Не индексируется сайт

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, seo, поисковые-системы, поисковая-оптимизация

Всем привет! Подскажите, пожалуйста, по какой причине сайт может не индексирыватся?
Google Search пишет, что страницы "Исключены" и мол страницы были исключены скорей всего по моей воли, в Yandex Webmaster тоже не индексирует.
Сайт на wordpress + woocomeerce.

Возможно что то нет так с robots.txt?

Так же имеется плагин Yoast SEO

По пути Настройки - Чтение, индексация включена

Вот сам robots.txt

```html
User-agent: *
Disallow: /stranica-magazina/
Disallow: /uk/storinka-magazinu/
Disallow: /he/shop/
Disallow: /cgi-bin
Disallow: /?
Disallow: /wp-
Disallow: /wp/
Disallow: *?s=
Disallow: *&s=
Disallow: /search/
Disallow: /author/
Disallow: /users/
Disallow: */trackback
Disallow: */feed
Disallow: */rss
Disallow: */embed
Disallow: */wlwmanifest.xml
Disallow: /xmlrpc.php
Disallow: *utm*=
Disallow: *openstat=
Disallow: /cart/
Disallow: /checkout/
Disallow: /*add-to-cart=*

Allow: */uploads
Allow: /*/*.js
Allow: /*/*.css
Allow: /wp-*.png
Allow: /wp-*.jpg
Allow: /wp-*.jpeg
Allow: /wp-*.gif
Allow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Sitemap: https://nellys-charm.com.ua/sitemap_index.xml
```

Comment: Сайт в выдаче и гугла и яндекса. А такой роботс лучше удалить. В нём должно быть только то что может проиндексироваться, но тебе не надо. Хотя к такому такое лучше вообще запрещать доступ и не светить в роботсе.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но тогда какой же оптимальный robots.txt для сайта на wordpress + woocommerce?

Comment: ВП сам сгенерирует нужный. А если вдруг в выдачу попадёт что-то ненужное - тогда это и закроешь.